# Reflection texture from FBO getting to correct image

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw

I am using the A FBO to capture the reflection above the surface of the quad. The premise is to move the camera under the water surface then render the scene to the fbo, then revert to the original viewing position like this:

```
WaterFrameBuffer fbos;


Water test(fbos.getReflectionTexture(), fbos.getRefractionTexture());
render->addWater(&test);
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    GLfloat currentFrame = (float)glfwGetTime();
    deltaTime = currentFrame - lastFrame;
    lastFrame = currentFrame;
    gameController->update(deltaTime);

    //reflection buffer
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    fbos.bindReflectionFrameBuffer();
    float distance = 2 * (gameController->getGameCamera()->GetCameraPosition().y - 0);
    gameController->getGameCamera()->GetCameraPosition().y -= distance;
    gameController->getGameCamera()->flipPitch();
    render->renderScene();
    gameController->getGameCamera()->GetCameraPosition().y += distance;
    gameController->getGameCamera()->flipPitch();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    //refraction buffer
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    fbos.bindRefractionFrameBuffer();
    render->renderScene();
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
    glViewport(0, 0, SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT);

    render->renderScene();
    render->renderWater();
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
```

However I am getting this as a result: [image: refraction + reflection]

The refraction image is correct however the reflection is not taking the correct image. This is the reflection by itself[image]

This is the fragment shader I am using:

```
  #version 330 core
   in vec3 ourColor;
   in vec4 clipSpace;
   in vec2 texC;
    out vec4 color;

 // Texture samplers
   uniform sampler2D reflectTex;
   uniform sampler2D refractTex;
   //uniform sampler2D dudvTex;
void main()
{
   vec3 ndc = (clipSpace.xyz / clipSpace.w)/ 2.0 + 0.5;
   vec2 reflectTexCoords = vec2(ndc.x, -ndc.y);
   vec2 refractTexCoords = vec2(ndc.x, ndc.y);

   //vec2 distortion1 = texture(dudvTex, vec2(texC.x, texC.y)).rg*2.0 - 1.0;
   //reflectTexCoords += distortion1;
   //refractTexCoords += distortion1;

    vec4 reflect = texture(reflectTex, reflectTexCoords);
    vec4 refract = texture(reflectTex, refractTexCoords);
    color = reflect;//mix(reflect,refract,0.5);
}
```

vertex shader:

```
  #version 330 core
  layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
   layout (location = 1) in vec3 color;
  layout (location = 2) in vec2 texCoord;

   out vec3 ourColor;
   out vec4 clipSpace;
   out vec2 texC;
   uniform mat4 model;
   uniform mat4 view;
   uniform mat4 projection;
   const float tiling = 6.0;
   void main()
   {
       clipSpace = projection*view*model *vec4(position, 1.0f);
       gl_Position = clipSpace;
       ourColor = color;
       texC = texCoord;
    }
```

Any ideas how to fix this or a alternate way to get the reflection image?

Comment: Sorry this is the fragment shader program. Clipspace is used to calculate the pixel where the texture is meant to be mapped, without this the texture will rotate with the camera instead.

Comment: just edited it in sorry about that.

Comment: ok yea just tried it. https://gyazo.com/c491186d3ffa59bf5391e6ddba7cdda4

Comment: https://gyazo.com/96a03d3f55435ef060af398911472cc6 this is the result without mixing refraction and reflection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the you have set the texture wrap parameters for `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S` and `GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T` to `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`. See [`glTexParameter`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/es3.0/html/glTexParameter.xhtml).

This causes that any texture coordinate are clamped to the range `[0+1/(2*texturSize), 1-1/(2*textureSize)]`.

To solve your issue you have either to use the texture wrap parameter `GL_REPEAT`, or you have to ensure that the texture coordinates are in range [0.0, 1.0].

The issue in the above image is the negation of the `y` component of the texture coordinate (`-ndc.y`), which causes that the texture coordinate is in range[0.0, -1.0]. Move the coordinate into the range[1.0, 0.0] and use `1.0 - ndc.y` instead:

```
vec2 reflectTexCoords = vec2(ndc.x, 1.0 - ndc.y);
```

Comment: "This causes that any texture coordinate blow 0.0 is always set to 0.0 and any texture coordinate above 1.0 is always set to 1.0." Not exactly. This is waht the old and now deprecated `GL_CLAMP` mode did. `CLAMP_TO_EDGE` clamps to `[0+1/(2*texturSize), 1-1/(2*textureSize)]`, which are the coordinates of the texel _centers_ of the outermost texels.

Comment: That worked great! I already had the texture coordinates within 0,1 so all  did was change -ndc.y to 1 - ndc,y. Thanks for the help.